# Yii framework: populate data from related table

Tags: php, database, yii, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables Customer and Location. Location has fields id, country, zone, state and city. Customer table has a foreign key location_id.

While creating a customer, I need to display dropdowns for country, zone, state and city on the create customer form and the values in the dropdown should be populated from the location table. When a user selects these fields, the corresponding location id should be saved in the location_id field of the Customer table.

While updating a customer, values for country, zone, state and city dropdowns should be populated in the form based on the location_id foreign key. Any changes in the values of these dropdowns should be saved as location_id foreign key.

Any inputs or pointers to any existing posts/articles will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

> Any inputs or pointers to any existing posts/articles will be of great help.

OK, some hints

### 1.

> values in the dropdown **should be populated** from the location table.

For this, i think, you need to get acquainted with the post on [dependent dropdowns in yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/) for populating one dropdown when choosing from another one.

### 2.

> When a user selects these fields, the corresponding location id **should be saved** in the location_id field of the Customer table.

For this you might need to do some ajax call upon dropdown/textField selection/changing. You might do this by external js function but i recommend the [Select2 with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/). 
For example here on item change in Select2 the ajax call is performed to the controller `eventsPerformance` and action `save` with data as serialization of the whole form `js:$("#performance-form").serialize()`:

```
 $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
    'attribute' => 'subStatus',
    'model'=>$performance,        
    'data'=>$subStatusArray,
    'htmlOptions'=>array( 
        'onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST',
        'url'=>'eventsPerformance/save',
        'data'=>'js:$("#performance-form").serialize()',)),
    ),  
 ));
```

Feel free to ask if some more help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is nothing special. Just use methods whose name starts with `active` and your dropdowns will preselect right option. I believe you are using [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) to create your [CRUD operations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app#implementing-crud-operations). So you need only to add Location dropdows in users `update` / `create` view. E.g.

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(99);
$locations = Location::model()->findAll();
$locationList = CHtml::listData($locations, 'id', 'country');

echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($user, 'location_id', $locationList);
```

But I think your description is not correct because in your `Location` table one ID identify whole combination of country-zone-state-city, i.e.:

```
1 | USA | NULL | Arizona | Phoenix
2 | ... | ...
```

If you need drop-downs for every of them, you need to create separate DB tables.

```
// countries
id | title

// cities
id | country_id | title
```